# Unable to open PHP files on Linux platform on Ubuntu

Tags: php

I've copied over my files over to a new directory which I have created: `/var/www/worm/data.php`.
I tried opening it by a few ways:

1. Double clicking the file but nothing comes out
2. Typing `localhost/worm/data.php` into search browser, but nothing comes out either.
   Can someone please guide or tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the file permissions. You might not have the permission to read the file. You can use the `chmod` command to change permissions. You may also check the `chown` command. Once you have set the permissions correctly you should be able to open files using a text editor.

To open the file using `localhost/worm/data.php`, firstly make sure permissions are set properly to the files. The other thing to consider is to check if apache and php are installed or not. If they are not installed check the [Apache Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, now type `sudo -H gedit`, then type your password and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. This will open the gEdit program with root permission. Now open your .php file where it's located or just drag the file into gEdit.

Answer (score 0):

First let us identify what you mean to open php files:

Open for editing **OR** Open in web browser.

To open for editing just right click on the file and choose `open with text Editor`

To open in web browser you should have a web server. The most popular is apache. you can install it by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Also you have to install php on your system

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Now to open the file copy it to the `/var/www` directory and then navigate in your browser to `localhost/file.php`

Comment: I've already apache2 and php5 installed and the server is running, but whenever i open it on browser, it's just a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need a web server to view php files.

Install apache2 the default webserver.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

then install php5

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

then restart your apache2 server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

then just drop the php file(s) in the /var/www folder
and go to

```
http://localhost/file.php
```

but replace file.php with the name of the file

More information here
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html